# Using Gaussian Window to subdue the background in the facial recognition process

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, image-recognition

I am trying to perform facial recognition with a set of 28 database images (4 per person for 7 person). Each person has 2 images each taken in 2 very different backgrounds. Every image has face of the individual at the center of the image.

Initially when I ran the facial recognition algorithm for images of 7 people (2 each, in same background) my algorithm worked all fine and dandy. However, upon addition of face-images in different background, the algorithm did not work as intended, signalling to the fact that background in the images are causing problems.

I read the paper by Matthew Turk and Alex Pentland and they suggest multiplying the images by a two dimensional Gaussian Window centered  at the face. I tried doing so, however, performance of facial-recognition algorithm did not improve.

Could anyone possibly help me understand this process associated with the two-dimensional Gaussian Window and how it applies to facial recognition? Turk and Pentland claim that this process worked for them.

I used the following formula for two dimensional Gaussian pdf at the pixel location (x,y):

[image]

Comment: This is an out of topic question, SO is for programmation questions. Anyway it seems completely straigthforward: it acts like an elliptical mask that left the pixels of the face at their value (or almost) and set the background pixels at 0.

Comment: @Ratbert I understand the straightforward explanation of yours. I posted to see if anyone had similar problems employing the Gaussian Window, and if they did, how did they get rid of the problems?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Matthew Turk and Alex Pentland are talking about filtering the image with a 2d Gaussian matrix, though I am not familiar with the paper.  A filter can be thought of either a convolution in the time domain -OR- a *multiplication* in the frequency domain.  If you were to filter an image with a 2d Gaussian, the effect would be a smoother version of the image. See below:

Consider an original (unfiltered) picture:

[image: Original Picture]

Filtered with a Gaussian matrix:

[image: Gaussian Mask]

With the result a 'smoothed' version of the original:

[image: Smoothed or Filtered Result]

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the facial-recognition algorithm that I am pursuing, the operation you mentioned is not what I need. In fact during fledgling stages of my algorithm, I did try convolution to no avail.

In fact what I am doing is just multiplying the image matrix by a two dimensional Gaussian matrix elementwise, which gave me a new image with prominence in face parts and subduing the background parts.

However, I have the option to do that at various stages of my algorithm and doing so at some stages is optimal than other. I wanna see if anyone had the same problem and have suggestion about the stage at which I should use my Gaussian.